# Groups As Graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

In the book *Groups As Graphs* written by `W. B. Vasantha Kandasamy` and `Florentin Smarandache`, they represent graphs in terms of a group. The elements of the group are vertices and two elements $x, y$ in the group are adjacent or can be joined by an edge if $x.y = e$ ($e$, identity element of the group and $.$ is the operator).

In page 17 it shows an example of the graph of $Z_2 = \{0,1\}$ under addition
modulo $2$. The book says:

The identity graph of $Z_2$ is

[image]

as $1+1 = 0(\text{mod }2)$, $0$ is the identity of $Z_2$.

The problem is, by definition $0$ and $1$ should be connected only if $0+1 = 0(\text{mod }2)$ not the $1+1 = 0(\text{mod }2)$. But the book connected $0$ and $1$ because $1+1 = 0(\text{mod }2)$.

thanks

Comment: Close the book and walk away. https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3bd1qh/is_florentin_smarandache_a_real_mathematician/

Comment: I read some of it, and it does not seem to have high quality. At the very least, the language is difficult to understand, and that does not bode well for overall quality.

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes skimming through the book. To be clear, the book is not just "confusing and poorly written". (That description could fairly be applied to many mathematical texts which are nevertheless valuable.) It is mathematically totally vacuous, and contains completely false statements: for example, a totally wrong definition of groupoid.

Comment: That being said, there are a few common ways of making a graph representation of a group. For instance, you have the one used in the wikipedia [list of small groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups), which is made by drawing one cycle for each (primitive) cyclic subgroup. Or you can take a generating set for your group, and draw lines of different colours between each of the elements, representing multiplication by the generators (so each node has one in-edge and one out-edge of each colour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, they do state "It is by convention every element is
adjoined with the identity of the group $G$." However, I agree with the comments that you should close the book and find another one to study. After spending a little time reading this one, it is confusing and poorly written to say the least.